# Visual Studio double project not in sync

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14

**Question**

I have Visual Studio 2017 and I created a C++ windows console application with two projects nested in it. When I start my project without debugging, only one of the two project's outputs shows up. So how can I have both projects run one after another?

**Code**

Project #1

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "Project #1 is working.";
    return 0;
}
```

Project #2

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "Project #2 is working.";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Project #1 is working.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate programs in your solution which are compiled to separate executables. You can set one project as start Project in your solution and this exe is launched.

You can start any project by the context menu (right mouse button) by Debug - start new instance. Then either project 1 or project 2 are executed.
[image]

If you want to execute both with only one start you have to restructure your solution. Change (at least) one of your projects to create a library. Change corresponding `main` method either to an externally callable method or a class with methods and use it from the other projects `main`method.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but could you please clarify on your second paragraph, because I'm confused on how to get to the context menu.

Comment: In the now included screenshot of the context menu. You know, hat you can click with the right mouse button on any Project (not only on the solution!)  in solution explorer and there are a lot of possibilities for that project available?